# Take an array reference `T(&)[n]` to the contents of a `std::array<T, n>`

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

Suppose I have a `std::array<T, n>` and want to take an array reference to its contents (i.e. to the non-exposed `elems` array member).

I was surprised to find that `std::array<T, n>::data()` returns `T *` and not `T (&)[n]`, so it seems that some kind of cast is necessary.  I can write:

```
std::array<int, 5> arr;
int (&ref)[5] = *reinterpret_cast<int (*)[5]>(arr.data());
```

However, this looks ugly and potentially unsafe.  Is it legitimate (well-defined) code and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I suggest a reusable `constexpr` function template to hide that ugliness.

Comment: The corner case would be when the size is 0, in which case the right hand side would be undefined behavior, although in that particular case, the left hand side would not even compile (i.e. you cannot declare an array of 0 elements)

Comment: Using `arr.size()` rather than `5` would be less brittle (it's `constexpr` and so can be used as an array size). I'm not sure whether the cast is well-defined, though.

Answer (score 3):

The standard doesn't provide for the underlying implementation of `array`, but *if* it uses `int[5]` as the underlying representation, then for that implementation only your cast would be (non-portably) legal. For any other underlying representation you violate the strict aliasing rules and enter undefined behavior.

Instead of trying to return the array as an array, can you use iterator pairs to delimit the range you're interested in, following precedent with the standard library?

Comment: The elements are stored contiguously (23.3.2.1p1) so shouldn't it be possible to alias as an array anyway?

Comment: @ecatmur Only if the original underlying type in `array` is the type you cast it too - otherwise it's undefined behavior by mis-aliasing the original type. Consider a compiler that chose to implement the space as `aligned_storage` or something else other than an actual array.

Comment: @MarkB: But the `data()` member must provide access to that data as a *dynamic* array, which has the same memory layout as a regular array. I am inclined to say that it is almost always safe to do this (otherwise horrible) cast. I.e. `data()` already aliases the internal representation in an *array-compatible* way

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas I actually happen to agree with that: practically speaking it's almost certainly safe and I'm just pointing out that language-wise it's probably not legal and that there may be a legal alternative that would solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

The array in C++ is a defective type (here I am talking about c-style array, not `std::array`). The reason of that is because the size of the array isn't stored anywhere in the memory, it is known only at compile-time. Right as you cast array to some other type (commonly, to a pointer), the size of the array is lost.

Now you can see that reverse cast cannot be performed, because there is no way compiler could know size of an array, looking only at the pointer to the first member. As was already suggested, you could use a pair of iterators instead.